# How to create complete installer for ASP.Net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, installation

I'm programmed a web application on visual studio by ASP.Net C# and local database. then i want to create installer for this web application to do these actions on a target PC:

1. Install requirements for database
2. Install IIS on PC
3. Publish my Web Application as an website on IIS

**NOTE**

Actually, this web application should be run on a LAN that consist 3 PC and one router. one of that PC's should be a server and the web application must be installed on that system, then the other PC's getting to use from web application on a LAN.

**Update**

I'm used from Advanced Installer and setup works fine. but when i start the website in client system, always get this error:

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.*

and this is my connection string in web.config:

```
<add 
  name="SetupTestEntities" 
  connectionString="metadata=
  res://*/Model.csdl|
  res://*/Model.ssdl|
  res://*/Model.msl;
  provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
  provider connection string=&quot;
  data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
  attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\SetupTest.mdf;
  integrated security=True;
  connect timeout=30;
  MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Professional edition of [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/). This edition has support to install:

- [IIS web sites, app pools, web apps and virtual directories](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-iis.html)
- [install windows features](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/windows-features.html) without writing any scripting
- [install prerequisites](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/predefined-prerequisites.html), thus your requirements for your database

Advanced Installer also supports running SQL scripts, so you could create on the fly your databases and populate them with your defaults, but this feature is available in the Enterprise edition.

In the end Advanced Installer will build and MSI or EXE installer as output (depending on what you want), that you can use to deliver your application to any machine.

(disclaimer: I work on this product)

Comment: Is this the best tools to creating installer with mentioned features?

Comment: see what other users have to say about it:  http://www.advancedinstaller.com/testimonials.html

Comment: what is the database needed to install on client system to run the application with local database **(.mdf file)** on him/her system? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459652/what-is-the-database-needed-to-run-web-application-with-local-database-file

Comment: SQL Express should do the job.

Comment: I installed SQL Server Express LocalDB and the application works fine.