# What is the database needed to run web application with local database file?

Tags: asp.net, installation, local-database

I programmed a web application that uses from local database **(.mdf file)** and would be run locally on client system.
my question is that what is the database needed to install on client system to run this application.
MS SQL Server?
MS SQL Server Express
or nothing?

Comment: The `.mdf` file type is associated with Microsoft SQL Server, if that's what you are asking.  Unless the .mdf file is more than a couple of gigabytes in size, you can probably get away with using Express.

Comment: Are you mean that if I install the `SQL Server Express` on client system, he can run and use from this application successfully?