# How to create installation wizard for ASP.net web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Actually my question is almost similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720907/how-to-create-complete-installer-for-asp-net-web-application) question.
But I have more demands to satisfy.
Actually my web project is developed with ASP.net and C#.And I build it using a tool call "Nant" because I want to install this web project to DotNetNuke(DNN).
So I can create build file using "Nant" tool and then I want to make intallation wizard to host this web project in another computer.
So following demands should be satisfied

1. I need to install required databases in client computer.
2. I need to update the connection string in web.config file based the database.
3. I need to create ODBC connection and save their names in my project    config file.
4. I need to create an application in application pool of IIS.
5. I need to host my project in IIS.

So question in the link I provided is suggested to use professional edition of advance installer to do this.Actually I have no idea about Advance installer can satisfy all of my demands.
But I want some other solution to do this? Can't I create my own installation wizard by coding?  Aren't there any visual studio libraries which can help me?
Please help me.
Thanking you

Comment: _"I have no idea about Advance installer can satisfy all of my demands"_ - so download the 30 trial and find out

Comment: Even though it fits me, I am not in position to purchase such a tool..This is why I am asking for any other alternative..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use install shield to do the basic operation. lets go through your steps one by one.

1. List item installshield has the db folder path and files to move, you can use installshield directory variables to get the path e.g [TARGETDIR]
2. There is a work around for this, don't put that connection string in webconfig, make a simple text file and put it inside, this may require a little bid code change as well,where you are accessing it. if you dont want to do so read the details after steps.
3. same as 2,
4. supported by installed shield
5. supported by installed shield

Ok Now, for step 2 and step 3, you can also use the webconfig and project file but for this you need to make a console application and parse the files to replace connectionstring etc. Put it under your project and set the target path via installshield of target machine.
this will act like a batch file and you can run it by adding custom actions to your project.
To see how to run any console app or batch follow this
[How to run a ".bat" file during installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414956/how-to-run-a-bat-file-during-installation)

Comment: Thanking you UmarKashmiri..But aren't there any other cheaper solutions?I mean any libraries for visual studio?

Comment: installshield express is free.